# JRadioButton en TitledBorder

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Cómo puedo implementar una radio button donde va el titulo de un title border?
Es lo único que no se como hacer para poner allí ese componente, aclaro, no quiero que el radiobutton este dentro del titleborder, si nó que el radio button esté donde suele ir el título del titled border.

Comment: Podrías compartir el código del elemento donde quieres agregar el botón? Ayudaría mucho en que la gente te pueden dar respuestas concretas a lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay una opcion llamada Absolute Layout que te da el permiso de colocar cualquier cosa donde tu quieras, de lo contrario solo te dejara agregar elementos en su correspondiente panel o border

Comment: Correcto, existe un Absolute Layout que permite posicionar elementos con coordenadas, pero es dudable si eso va ser la solución, cuando se aclara un poco más la pregunta.